# directory keeps getting made after boot causing mounted drive to be bumped to another location

Tags: 18.04

I was trying to setup a folder on my Ubuntu (18.04) RAID drive to be a Time-Machine backup but now when I reboot, it automatically appears under `/media/name/RAID` with the contents

```
/media/name/RAID/
  Time-Machine
      config
          avahi
```

All empty. How to I stop this folder being created every time the computer boots? I don't want the Time-Machine on Ubuntu backup anymore.

I want to mount my RAID drive after logging in and when I click it to load in Finder, it is being forced to mount at `/media/name/RAID1` instead of `/media/name/RAID` because the above folder is being created just after logging in.

I looked in `/etc/netatalk/afp.conf` and `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and found nothing unusual (I believe they are now default).

Another thing - when I `sudo rm -f RAID` it just re-appears after 5-10 seconds.

Note: this isn't anything to do with the RAID drive, it just so happens to be the drive that stored the Time-Machine folder that I was going to use.

Comment: Apologies, it is 18.04, not 16. Hopefully the question can be passed through?

Comment: Add your volume to `/etc/fstab` and give it a specific mount directory. Don't use `/media/raid...`, but for example `/srv/Time-Machine/`. Use `noauto` mount option for no automatic mount. In example: You may put this line into your `/etc/fstab` - `/dev/RAIDDEVICE /srv/Time-Machine ext4,xfs,btrfs noauto 0 0`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to remove the Time-Machine folder issue, not mount anything elsewhere as they are already where I want them. Sure I can get around by mounting the RAID elsewhere, but I still have this Time-Machine folder being made from an unknown source.